# Letter Frequency program function calls Java

Tags: java

I am trying to code a letter frequency program that counts the alphabetic characters from a .txt file and presents the frequency data in a 2 column table. I am struggling to call the function char2int from the function processFile. I am not sure if I need to use an if statement or not as well. Also I am summing up all the alphabetic characters and other characters. If someone can help explain what I am doing wrong I'd be grateful.

Here is my code:

```
final static int AlphabetSize = 26;
final static Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
final static PrintStream cout = System.out;
final static int MaxBarLength = 50;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName;


    // get the file name
    cout.print("Enter the file name: ");
    fileName = cin.nextLine();

    // process the file
    try {
        processFile(fileName);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // end try


} // end main

static void processFile(final String fileName) 
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{ 
    FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    int inputValue;

    // declare other variables you need
            int counters [] = new int [26];
               int alpha = 0;
               int num = 0;
               int ticker = 0;

    // get the first character from file
    inputValue = inFile.read();
    while (inputValue != -1) {
        char ch = (char) inputValue;

        // add code to process this character
                  if (){
            counters[char2int(ch)]++;
                    alpha++;
                }else{
                      num++;
                  }
        // read next input character
        inputValue = inFile.read();
    } // end loop

    inFile.close();
        System.out.println("\nThe data file has " + alpha + " alphabetic, and " + num + " other characters.\n");
    // generate appropriate output
            display(counters);


} // end function

static void display(final int [] counters) {
    // write code for this function

    System.out.println("Letter" + " " + "Count" + " " + "Bar");
    System.out.println("------" + " " + "-----" + " " + "---");
   printChars(counters);
   } // end function

// char2int is complete
static int char2int(final char arg) {
    if (!Character.isLetter(arg))
        return -1;
    else
        return (int) Character.toUpperCase(arg) - (int) 'A';
} // end function


// function printChars writes n copies of the character c to the
// standard output device
static void printChars (final int[] counters) {
    // write the code
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
       System.out.printf("%c%7d\n", i + 'A', counters[i]);

   }


 // end printChars


} // end function
```

Comment: This is more of a style thing im referring to rather than an actual problem with your code, but you should try and always use open close brackets for if else statements even if they aren't technically needed for single statement `if/else`

Comment: What are you struggling with? I.e. what have you tried to do and why did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally do it this way William:

```
int c = char2int(ch);
if (c >= 0) { 
    counters[c]++;
    alpha++;
}
else { num++; }
```

You should also consider taking care of non-alphabetic characters should there be any within the text file. This can also be handled within the **char2int()** method.